# How to align multiple divs within a div ,horizontally with equal space-between

Tags: html, css

I know there are so many questions on this topic but I can seem to find a way to sort it out..
Im new to `css` and I am trying to re-create the simple box within a box method..

Heres the link to my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Coooky87/pen/podqQdV)

And here is the `.html` to give further context..

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </script>
</head>

<body class="body">
<!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </nav>
<!-- Header Boxes -->
        <div class="header-box">
            <div class="child-box-1">
                <div class="child-box-2">
                    <div class="child-box-3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, `class = 'header-box'` needs to house `child-box-1`,`child-box-2`,`child-box-3`, so there would essentially be a red, yellow and black box within the main blue box..

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400&family=Montserrat&display=swap');
    
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color:rgb(57, 67, 77);
    }
    
    .navbar {
        padding: 20;
        margin: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        background-color:rgb(57, 67, 77);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    h1 {
        padding-top: 10;
        margin: 0;
        font-family:'Montserrat';
        color: whitesmoke;
        font-size: xx-large;
    }
    
    .header-box {
        padding:0;
        margin: 10;
        max-width: 100%;
        height:200px;
        background-color: blue;
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .child-box-1 {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 10;
        background: red;
        width: 32%;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 1%;
    }
    
    .child-box-2 {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 10;
        background: yellow;
        width: 32%;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 1%;
    }
    
    .child-box-3 {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 10;
        background: black;
        width: 32%;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 1%;
      
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body class="body">
    <!-- Navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </nav>
    <!-- Header Boxes -->
            <div class="header-box">
                <div class="child-box-1"></div>
              <div class="child-box-2"></div>
              <div class="child-box-3"></div>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header-box {
    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightblue;

    padding: 10px 20px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-box > div {
    width: 50px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-box">
  <div class="child-box-1"></div>
  <div class="child-box-2"></div>
  <div class="child-box-3"></div>
</div>
```